# How to programmatically install a NuGet package?

Tags: c#, nuget

I want to programmatically install a NuGet package to a project, and update the `.csproj` file, and the `packages.config` file.

I am using the official `Nuget.core` framework which source code is available here: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2

**I am not** using the NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Core/
But the source code found on GitHub to be able to do some debugging.

> Note: I am using the version `2.11` and not the `2.13`

I am able to download a package at a desired directory and update the `packages.config` file:

```
// ---- Download and install a package at a desired path ----
string packageID = "Newtonsoft.json";
var sourceUri = new Uri("https://packages.nuget.org/api/v2");

// Return an IPackage
var package = GetNugetPackage(packageID, sourceUri);

IPackageRepository sourceRepository = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(sourceUri.ToString());

string packagesPath = "../../TestFiles/packages";
PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(sourceRepository, packagesPath);

packageManager.InstallPackage(packageID, SemanticVersion.Parse(package.Version.ToFullString()));

// ---- Update the ‘packages.config’ file ----
var packageReferenceFile = new PackageReferenceFile("../../TestFiles/packages.config");

// Get the target framework of the current project to add --> targetframework="net452" attribute in the package.config file
var currentTargetFw = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TargetFrameworkAttribute), false);
var targetFrameworkAttribute = ((TargetFrameworkAttribute[])currentTargetFw).FirstOrDefault();

// Update the packages.config file    
packageReferenceFile.AddEntry(package.GetFullName(), SemanticVersion.Parse(package.Version.ToFullString()), false, new FrameworkName(targetFrameworkAttribute.FrameworkName));
```

**Now I need to update the `.csproj` and here is the tricky part...**

Here's what I tried so far:

```
string csprojFilePath = "../../TestFiles/test.csproj";
var project = new MSBuildProjectSystem(csprojFilePath);

string pathToAnExistingNugetPackageDll = "../../TestFiles/packages/Newtonsoft.json/lib/net45/Newtonsoft.json.dll"

project.AddReference(pathToAnExistingNugetPackageDll, Stream.Null);
project.Save();
```

This piece of code update the `.csproj` file, it add a new `reference` node like this:

```xml
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.json">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.json\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.json.dll</HintPath>      
</Reference>
```

But I need a **complete** `reference` node like this:

```xml
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.json, Version=9.0.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f4f7d11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.json\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.json.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: You will need to generate the reference yourself with your own code. That particular style of reference is generated by Visual Studio and not by NuGet. NuGet generates the reference with an Include attribute that does not use the full assembly name.

Comment: I found a class which seem to do the trick in the Core assembly: 'RemoteAssembly' it seem to load my needed attributes... I'll give it a try

Comment: @Thomas , `MSBuildProjectSystem` could not be found. Could you give its assembly reference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to **@MattWard** and **@bashis**, i've written my own code generator:

So, to add properly a reference into a given `.csproj` here's what I do:

```
var CsprojDoc = new XmlDocument();
CsprojDoc.LoadXml("*your_csproj_content*");
var Nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(CsprojDoc.NameTable);
Nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");

IPackage packageInfos = GetNugetPackage(packageId, packageRepositoryUri);

XmlNode referenceNode = CsprojDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Reference", XmlNamespaceValue);
XmlAttribute includeAttribute = CsprojDoc.CreateAttribute("Include");

var targetFwProfile = CsprojDoc.SelectSingleNode("//x:TargetFrameworkProfile", Nsmgr);
string targetFrameworkProfile = string.Empty;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetFwProfile?.InnerXml))
{
    targetFrameworkProfile = targetFwProfile.InnerXml;
}

var targetFwAttribute = GetTargetFrameworkFromCsproj();
Regex p = new Regex(@"\d+(\.\d+)+");
Match m = p.Match(targetFwAttribute.FrameworkName);
Version targetFwVersion = Version.Parse(m.Value);

// Get the package's assembly reference matching the target framework from the given '.csproj'.
var assemblyReference =
    packageInfos.AssemblyReferences
        .Where(a => a.TargetFramework.Identifier.Equals(targetFwAttribute.FrameworkName.Split(',').First()))
        .Where(a => a.TargetFramework.Profile.Equals(targetFrameworkProfile))
        .Last(a => (a.TargetFramework.Version.Major.Equals(targetFwVersion.Major) && a.TargetFramework.Version.Minor.Equals(targetFwVersion.Minor)) ||
        a.TargetFramework.Version.Major.Equals(targetFwVersion.Major));

DownloadNugetPackage(packageInfos.Id, packageRepositoryUri, packagesFolderPath, packageInfos.Version.ToFullString());

string dllAbsolutePath = Path.GetFullPath($"{packagesFolderPath}\\{packageInfos.GetFullName().Replace(' ', '.')}\\{assemblyReference.Path}");
var assemblyInfos = Assembly.LoadFile(dllAbsolutePath);

includeAttribute.Value = $"{assemblyInfos.FullName}, processorArchitecture=MSIL";

referenceNode.Attributes.Append(includeAttribute);

XmlNode hintPathNode = CsprojDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "HintPath", XmlNamespaceValue);
XmlNode privateNode = CsprojDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Private", XmlNamespaceValue);

hintPathNode.InnerXml = $"$(SolutionDir)\\packages\\{assemblyReference.Path}";
privateNode.InnerXml = "True";

referenceNode.AppendChild(hintPathNode);
referenceNode.AppendChild(privateNode);
var itemGroupNode = CsprojDoc.SelectSingleNode("//x:Project/x:ItemGroup/x:Reference", Nsmgr).ParentNode;
itemGroupNode.AppendChild(referenceNode);
```

Here's my `DownloadNugetPackage` method:

```
private static void DownloadNugetPackage(string packageId, Uri repoUri, string packagesFolderPath, string version)
{
    IPackageRepository packageRepository = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(repoUri.ToString());
    PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(packageRepository, packagesFolderPath);

    packageManager.InstallPackage(packageId, SemanticVersion.Parse(version));
}
```

My `GetTargetFrameworkFromCsproj`

```
    public static TargetFrameworkAttribute GetTargetFrameworkFromCsproj()
    {
        XmlNode targetFrameworkNode = CsprojDoc.SelectSingleNode("//x:TargetFrameworkVersion", Nsmgr);
        return new TargetFrameworkAttribute($".NETFramework, Version={targetFrameworkNode.InnerXml}");
    }
```

And my `GetNugetPackage` method:

```
public static IPackage GetNugetPackage(string packageId, Uri repoUri, string version = null)
{
    IPackageRepository packageRepository = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(repoUri.ToString());
    IPackage package;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(version))
    {
        package = packageRepository.FindPackagesById(packageId).SingleOrDefault(p => p.Version.ToFullString().Equals(version));
    }
    else
    {
        package = packageRepository.FindPackagesById(packageId).SingleOrDefault(p => p.IsLatestVersion);
    }

    return package;
}
```

> Note: This time, i'm using the official NuGet package: **Nuget.core 2.14**: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Core/
>
> Note 2: When I add a new `Reference` node, in the `processorArchitecture` attribute, I've hard coded the value: `MSIL`

*If you want to test it, you might tweak it a bit.*

This work fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and providing an answer, I don't need this myself but it's a rare (but very welcome) sight :-)

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you are writing the code generator on your own)

I am not sure this is the best solution but you could try something like this:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("path_to_dll");
string info = assembly.FullName; // contains something like "AssemblyName, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=foobar"
```

which will add some overhead by loading the assembly, but will presumably do the job.

Comment: This will help me a lot, if I don't figured out how to make it work with nuget.core, i'll use your method to create my own generator.

Comment: I'm writing my own code generator, and your code do the trick, thanks