# Trying to install NuGet package programmatically - Package.GetGlobalService returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget, componentmodel

I'm trying to get the list of installed NuGet packages in my ASP.NET MVC application and I'm using NuGet.VisualStudio like this:

```
var componentModel = (IComponentModel)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel));
IVsPackageInstallerServices installerServices = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstallerServices>();
if (!installerServices.IsPackageInstalled(project, "TemplateBuilder"))
{
    var installer = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstaller>();
    installer.InstallPackage("All", project, "TemplateBuilder", (System.Version)null, false);
}
```

For some reasons I've put above code in `Global.asax.cs` file, but `componentModel` is always null.
Any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: Change `var componentModel = (IComponentModel)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel));` to `var bob = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel)); var componentModel = (IComponentModel)bob;`  What is `bob`? Is it null?

Comment: Yes, in that code `bob` is null

Comment: Does https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165439.aspx help?

Comment: No, I've read that before.

Answer (score 0):

> For some reasons I've put above code in Global.asax.cs file, but componentModel is always null. Any idea what's wrong with it?

According to the [IComponentModel Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.componentmodelhost.icomponentmodel.aspx), you can notice that the `icomponentModel` is a Interface in the in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.dll`, which is a Visual Studio SDK Reference. So if you use `IComponentModel`, you need the visual studio instance.
Generally, it used in the visual Studio Integrate project.

Besides, when you dig into the class `IsPackageInstalled`:

```
bool IsPackageInstalled(global::EnvDTE.Project project, string id);
```

You will need to pass the parameter **project**, but ASP.NET MVC project din't have any project object. So it seems that we could not use this method in the ASP.NET project in this situation.

If you want to install NuGet package programmatically, you can refer to [How to programmatically install a NuGet package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803738/how-to-programmatically-install-a-nuget-package/41895490#41895490) for more detail info.

Comment: According to the link, it needs a given `.csproj ` file, so could it be used in ASP.NET?

Comment: Yes, I`m not debug all scripts in that link, but I debug the GetNugetPackage method in a C# console application after install the nuget.core package, and build it successfully. I guess all scrpts in that link should be work in the ASP.NET, because this method use the NuGet API instead of Visual Studio SDK. https://blog.nuget.org/20130520/Play-with-packages.html

Comment: It doesn't work on ASP.NET, because it still needs project object

Comment: @MohammadSadeghipour, Sorry, where are you find it needs project object in the accepted answer in this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803738/how-to-programmatically-install-a-nuget-package/41895490#41895490?